# Change Accent Color of Atom

Tags: css, atom-editor

Hi there is there a way of changing Atom's accent color like the themes do it? I only want to change the accent color not the entire ui theme. This is my current setup.

[image]

I found a package that focuses on accent colors but I didn't like how it change the entire the ui theme because I prefer One Dark.

https://atom.io/packages/accents-ui

**So, How do I change the accent color of Atom?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing Atom's accent colour is not a simple case of changing one variable; themes modify numerous variables to achieve what appears to be a single, unified effect.

From looking through the [style files](https://github.com/kieranju/accents-ui/tree/master/styles) in the `accents-ui` theme, it looks like the main LESS variables used are:

```
@accent-color
@accent-color-subtle
@accent-color-bg
@base-background-color
@base-border-color
@base-accent-color
```

Try adding these to `style.less` and modify them to suit your accent colour of choice. You should also look through the various `.less` files in the `accents-ui` theme to pick out what you want to be included with this accent.

Comment: I see your point editing it all one by one will be a nightmare. I can see why the package developer made his own ui theme.

Answer (score 0):

It literally says it in the picture: You can also style Atom by editing your stylesheet...

There you have to change the CSS.

Comment: How do I do that in style.less?

Comment: Man, serious? Are you going to ask how to change something? It's Less, did you even search online for a how to?

Comment: Tell me then how do I change the accent color of atom via style.less?